# display data from webservice json android

Tags: android, json, video

```
hi here is my webservice code 

[{"video_id":"119","user_id":"127","video_poster":"http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/client/sedio/images/527901be41dfb91eea7e7825baee262f.jpg","fullname":"testacc268","channel":"Family", "title":"Fffffgffffgg","video_name":"http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/client/sedio/video/d2b6a230106f355d2eee796863f4088a.mp4","status":"1","total_like":"1", "total_vine":"1","video_created_date":"1 w","followers":"1", "following":"0","post_private":"0","post_sensitive":"0", "profile_image":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/489273121241722880/kGCUNK2Y_bigger.jpeg","user_like":"Unlike","user_vine":"Vine","location":""},{"video_id":"118","user_id":"127","video_poster":"http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/client/sedio/images/1ae825f39d90f209cb593a916ac9a048.jpg","fullname":"testacc268","channel":"", "title":"Fhgdfg","video_name":"http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/client/sedio/video/78105faebb9dfe0cf67b60ada04aca03.mp4","status":"1","total_like":"0", "total_vine":"0","video_created_date":"1 w","followers":"1", "following":"0","post_private":"0","post_sensitive":"0", "profile_image":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/489273121241722880/kGCUNK2Y_bigger.jpeg","user_like":"Unlike","user_vine":"Unvine","location":""},{"video_id":"117","user_id":"127","video_poster":"http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/client/sedio/images/131968331051b1173f913029f738efed.jpg","fullname":"testacc268","channel":"Dogs", "title":"Fhjvg","video_name":"http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/client/sedio/video/2ec8bfcd0cd960b0f3e079ca503fba5c.mp4","status":"1","total_like":"0", "total_vine":"0","video_created_date":"1 w","followers":"1", "following":"0","post_private":"0","post_sensitive":"0", "profile_image":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/489273121241722880/kGCUNK2Y_bigger.jpeg","user_like":"Unlike","user_vine":"Unvine","location":""},{"video_id":"116","user_id":"127","video_poster":"http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/client/sedio/images/131968331051b1173f913029f738efed.jpg","fullname":"testacc268","channel":"Dogs", "title":"Fhjvg","video_name":"http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/client/sedio/video/2ec8bfcd0cd960b0f3e079ca503fba5c.mp4","status":"1","total_like":"1", "total_vine":"0","video_created_date":"1 w","followers":"1", "following":"0","post_private":"0","post_sensitive":"0", "profile_image":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/489273121241722880/kGCUNK2Y_bigger.jpeg","user_like":"Like","user_vine":"Unvine","location":""},{"video_id":"115","user_id":"127","video_poster":"http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/client/sedio/images/982da2c7d7aa7fc4385266ccad6f0fb1.jpg","fullname":"testacc268","channel":"Dogs", "title":"pppppppppppppppppppppppppp","video_name":"http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/client/sedio/video/d7a5291b8871fa3b2d3364abefc0c074.mp4","status":"1","total_like":"1", "total_vine":"0","video_created_date":"1 w","followers":"1", "following":"0","post_private":"0","post_sensitive":"0", "profile_image":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/489273121241722880/kGCUNK2Y_bigger.jpeg","user_like":"Like","user_vine":"Unvine","location":""} ]
```

How can i display it on android?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Can you please read through [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Try first, and post relevant code and information, so people may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code, that show you have to retrieve data from your response, do same from all or required fields that you wants to show.

```
public void readingJson(String jsonString) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for(int i = 0 ; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String imgUrl = jsonObject.getString("video_poster");
            Log.e(TAG, "imgUrl = " + imgUrl);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: can u explain how to stream video by this way

Comment: can you give complete code to parse this json please

Comment: Inside loop you have jsonObject.getString("key_place_holder"); for any required value from json, just replace this place_holder. 

And video streaming is completely different scenario, I even don't know what your screen looks like. But now you can have video url as from json.

Comment: my screen is look like vine's video home page